# How to deploy a Jar from a library project

Tags: java, gradle, deployment

I have a library project in Java which is several folders, each one doing specific parts and having its own dependencies.
Since I am working locally I would like to deploy this library locally and get the Jar to import to another project.

For this reason I am using gradle and what I did was going to the directory where I have all the folders of the library and `gradle init` and then `gradle build`.
Since I want the files locally, I saw that I can use `gradle publishToMavenLocal`, which I did and it created a jar file under `~/.m2/....`. Now the issue is that this jar file appear to only contain a `META-INF` folder and inside of it a `manifest.mf` file.
[This](https://pastebin.com/raw/EHdcPxpz) is the `build.gradle` file used.

What am I doing wrong? Should I do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)
there is also a complete example.

be sure to add your sourceSets that you want to compile and build in the jar.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'java'
   id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDir 'src/main/java' }
        resources {
            srcDirs 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }

    test {
        java { srcDir 'src/test/java' }
        resources {
            srcDirs 'src/test/resources'
        }
    }


}

publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = 'org.gradle.sample'
                artifactId = 'project1-sample'
                version = '1.1'

                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also add your library project to your main project like this :

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile project(':library_project')
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'Project'
include ":library_project"
project(':library_project').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../library_project')
```

Comment: I have followed the exact same page you provided from gradle docs and i eventually have the `build.gradle` i provided above. The issue remains, the generated jar is empty

Comment: you need the java plugin to compile the source directory. the example above is working.